# PyTorch in-place operator issue in NumPy conversion

Tags: python, pytorch

I converted a PyTorch `Tensor` into a NumPy `ndarray`, and as it's shown below '`a`' and '`b`' both have different ids so they point to different memory locations.

I know in PyTorch underscore indicates in-place operation so `a.add_(1)` does not change the memory location of `a`, but why does it change the content of the array `b` (due to the difference in id)?

```
import torch
a = torch.ones(5)
b = a.numpy()
a.add_(1)

print(id(a), id(b))
print(a)
print(b)
```

Results:

```
139851293933696 139851293925904
tensor([2., 2., 2., 2., 2.])
[2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
```

[PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/tensor_tutorial.html#numpy-bridge):

> Converting a torch Tensor to a NumPy array and vice versa is a breeze.
> The torch Tensor and NumPy array will share their underlying memory
> locations, and changing one will change the other.

But why?
(They have different IDs so must be independent) :(

Comment: You almost answered your question. The array and tensor have their own memory locations, but each of their elements share the same memory location respectively.

Comment: @WholeBrain Thanks for your reply, But why they have different IDs?

Comment: @WholeBrain I mean different IDs is equal to having different memory locations.

Comment: The ids of both the containers are different. The ids of the contained elements are the same for both.

Comment: `(They have different IDs so must be independent) :(` This assertion is in fact wrong. They are different but not independant.

Comment: @WholeBrain wow! Are you sure? Thanks for clarifying. 

Comment: Well, not exactly (about the ids of the contained elements). Please refer to my proposed answer for a more accurate explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `numpy.ndarray.__array_interface__` and `torch.Tensor.data_ptr()`, you can find the memory location of their [data_array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.interface.html#object.__array_interface__).

```
a = torch.ones(5)
b = a.numpy()
a.add_(1)

print(b.__array_interface__)
# > {'data': (1848226926144, False),
#    'strides': None,
#    'descr': [('', '<f4')],
#    'typestr': '<f4',
#    'shape': (5,),
#    'version': 3}

print(a.data_ptr())
# > 1848226926144

a.data_ptr() == b.__array_interface__["data"][0]
# > True
```

Both the array and the tensor share the same data_array.

We can reasonably conclude that the method `torch.Tensor.numpy()` creates a numpy array from the Tensor by passing it the reference to its data_array.

```
b[0] = 4
print(a)
# > tensor([4., 2., 2., 2., 2.])
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is b is a pointer to a, and the memory addresses id() returns are just where they are stored in memory. Try using [copy.deepcopy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) to create a from b and that should make them entirely separate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how a Tensor points to a ndarray?!! As I know Tensors and arrays  only points to memory locations.

Comment: I would imagine both are pointing to the same chunk of memory that just holds all of the floats/doubles/whatever, and then the numpy array or pytorch tensor just looks at this same chunk of memory to get its values. [This post](https://www.jessicayung.com/numpy-arrays-memory-and-strides/) goes into how numpy stores arrays, I couldn't find anything super good on tensors though. 

Also, if you do b = a.detach().numpy() I think this should fix what you're seeing here. .detach() does the same thing as copy.deepcopy()